# Add a Ranking field and return top 3 data base on Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Thanks for looking into my question.

I want it to return the ranking and have it based on the "Date", "Group", "Sell Count" so it can give ranking for top 3. For example on 1/2/2014 John in "BIGGroup1A" sold  100 and 10. So the Rank will be 1 in product 10 and rank 2 in product 7. On the same day 1/2/2014, he sold 55 and 55 in two different groups so they both should be 1. I filled the rest of the ranking to match the logic im going after.

mytable is

```
Date    Name    Group          ProductName  SellCount
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product7    10
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product10   100
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1B  Product2    55
1/2/2014    John    Group1A         Product1    55
1/3/2014    John    Group1B         Product6    5
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product9    44
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product4    55
1/3/2014    John    LargeGroup1A    Product5    77
1/4/2014    John    LargeGroup2A    Product8    25
1/5/2014    John    LargeGroup2B    Product12   660
1/6/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product11   50
1/7/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product3    55
```

I want the result to be:

```
Date    Name    Group          ProductName  SellCount   Rank
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product7    10           2
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product10   100          1
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1B  Product2    55           1
1/2/2014    John    Group1A         Product1    55           1
1/3/2014    John    Group1B         Product6    5            1
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product9    44           2
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product4    55           1
1/3/2014    John    LargeGroup1A    Product5    77           1
1/4/2014    John    LargeGroup2A    Product8    25           1
1/5/2014    John    LargeGroup2B    Product12   660          1
1/6/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product11   50           1
1/7/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product3    55           1
```

I appreciate the solution in sql, I am new to it and hopefully everyone can help.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has a RANK() function.

Comment: Shouldn't the row for `1/6/2014` have rank 1 as it is the only item that day?

Comment: Yes you are correct I just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `rank()` window function like this:

```
select * from (
  select 
    *,
    rank = rank() over (partition by date, [group] order by date, [group], sellcount desc)
  from table1
) t 
where rank <= 3
```

The inner query assigns a rank to each row according to your specification and the outer query filter rows with rank > 3.

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8279b/6) for an example.

Comment: I tried that sql and everything returns as "Rank 1". Is there another function or filter that can give me results in the"Rank" field that i provide above? thanks for your help

Comment: @Nguyenal07 This ranking function will split the data into groups based on the partition clause, so as long as there are more than one items in a group (with different sellcount) the items should get different ranks. Are you sure the items are different? Look at the sample SQL Fiddle, it gives different ranks.

Comment: It didnt work because if i have 3 sell count on the same day, and two of them being 55 it will label both as 2. How do I get them to auto assign if one is two the otheris three for example it would look like this:Sell count 3 rank 2, sell count 3 rank 2, sell count 20, rank 1 -@jpw

Comment: @Nguyenal07 I'm not sure I follow, but if what you want is to have four rows returned with ranks 1, 2, 2, 3 if two products have the same value then maybe dense_rank is what you want to use. Take a look at this example where I changed the products for the BigGroup1B: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7a49/2

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused you, but the first one that you sent me has duplicates. I just want it to have rank 1,2,3 only. The first one shows rank 1,2,2. For example: sell count 50,50,100. I want it to be rank 1,2,3 if two sell count is equal can it auto assign one as 2 and 3 so it will be 1,2,3? Thanks

Comment: @Nguyenal07 Ok, then maybe row_number() would be the right tool? See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7a49/3

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I'm looking, maybe I need to add another criteria that should do it by now. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK()` to achieve what you want.

```
Select *, 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE,GROUP ORDER BY SELLCOUNT)AS RANK 
from Table T
```

`PARTITION BY` divides the result set into groups based on `DATE` and `GROUP.ORDER BY` ensures that ranking is based on `SELLCOUNT` in the groups created.